# Quel pronom personnel doit-on utiliser pour une entreprise constituée d'un seul employé ?

Tags: pronoms, conventions, style-de-rédaction

Je veux écrire un texte pour une entreprise constituée par actions. Cette entreprise est une personne morale au sens de la loi. Par contre, l'entreprise est constituée d'une seule personne, moi-même.

Le texte est pour un site web qui présente l'entreprise.

Je ne sais pas quel pronom personnel je dois utiliser. Puisque je suis la seule personne dans l'entreprise, je pourrais utiliser la première personne du singulier.

Exemple :

> J'offre mes services

Par contre, comme il ne s'agit pas d'une entreprise enregistrée en nom personnel, mais bien d'une société par actions qui représente une personne morale, je serais tenté d'utiliser un pronom autre que la première personne du singulier.

Exemple :

> Nous offrons des services…

Ou encore éviter l'utilisation de pronom personnel :

> L'entreprise offre des services…

Que dois-je faire dans une telle situation ?

Comment: Peut-être il serait bien de préciser de quel type de texte il s'agit et à qui il est destiné ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: En effet je vais mettre ma question à jour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour l'instant vous êtes la seule personne de l'entreprise. Mais cette dernière peut évoluer dans l'avenir en accueillant d'autres personnes, auquel cas le "*je*" perdrait son sens initial ("*moi, Gilles, au travers de l'entreprise XXX, ...*"). Il aurait alors une connotation beaucoup plus marketing et publicitaire. Le "*je*" passerait très bien si par exemple le texte de présentation était inclus dans une bulle de bande dessinée faisant parler le logo de l'entreprise.

Le "*nous*" semble donc de rigueur mais l'entreprise peut aussi être désignée par son nom ("*XXX vous permet de...*").

Cependant ceci ne vaut que s'il s'agit d'une société par actions. S'il s'agit d'une auto entreprise, le "*je*" pourrait passer puisque le côté "*moi, Gilles, au travers de l'entreprise XXX, ...*" est beaucoup plus présent dans l'entreprise.

Answer (score 6):

Pour moi la différence joue surtout sur la perception de celui qui sera en face du texte, la première personne du singulier donne plus une impression de proximité et de contact humain par rapport au client, tandis que l'usage de "nous" ou "l'entreprise" fait beaucoup plus formel.